# Magento2 : Error when running setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

I create a custom model and di.xml was written up, however when I try to run setup:di:compile, it said the

"generated/code/Magento/MediaStorage/Model/File/Storage/Response/Interceptor.php" file can't be deleted......No such file or directory

I am running docker at windows machine, I can see the files inside the folder, but I don't have permission to do it,  I did google the result but can't find any solution. such as "setup:static-content:deploy -f" or chmod 777

Any help would be appreciated..!

Thank in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

Chmod 777 - r var/generated/

setup:di:compile

İf i didnt work

Rm - rf var/generated/

Mkdir var/generated

Chmod 777 - r var/generated/

setup:di:compile